# When does the == operator depend on Equatable and when does it not?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of the following struct:

```
struct AtomCameraType
{
    var APIIdentifier: Input.HDRCamera
    var name: String

    init(...
}
```

That `APIIdentifier`, of type `Input.HDRCamera`, is a generated Google Protocol Buffer enum in Swift:

```
enum HDRCamera: SwiftProtobuf.Enum {
    typealias RawValue = Int
    case standard // = 1
    case sony // = 2
    case canon // = 3
    case panasonic // = 4
    case arri // = 5
    case jvc // = 6
    case red // = 7
    case rec2100 // = 8
    case fujifilm // = 9
    case nikon // = 10
    case proResRaw // = 11

    init() {
      self = .standard
    }
```

This may not conform to the Equatable protocol.

Attempts to match one of these enums against another with == works in a straight `if` statement, but fails when using == in `firstIndex(where:`.

So this works (cameraTypes is the aforementioned array of AtomCameraType):

```
for testType in AtomCamera.cameraTypes()  // array of struct AtomCameraType
{
    if testType.APIIdentifier == camType.APIIdentifier
    {
        debugPrint("Match found.")
    }
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
if let camIndex = AtomCamera.cameraTypes().firstIndex(where: { $0.APIIdentifier == camType.APIIdentifier })
{
    debugPrint("Match found.")
}
```

but finally, it works if I add rawValue:

```
if let camIndex = AtomCamera.cameraTypes().firstIndex(where: { $0.APIIdentifier.rawValue == camType.APIIdentifier.rawValue })
{
    // This works.
    ...
}
```

So it seems to me that == doesn't always need conformance to Equatable, but sometimes it does. Or is there something else going on here?

UPDATE: So, with no changes to this code, it now works. I made extensive changes in the AtomCamera object, but not to these structs or cameraTypes(). And, as you can see from the working/non-working examples (which I had in the code at the same time), they're both using the same call to cameraTypes() to fetch the array.

Returning to this issue, I looked for other firstIndex(where:) calls with similar structs and ==, and found that they worked. So I removed the ".rawValue" from this troublesome one experimentally... to find that the firstIndex now works. Baffling.

What's the protocol here? Delete this or close it, or just leave it?

Comment: "This may not conform to the Equatable protocol." what exactly does this mean? It *cannot*, *does not*, or *should not*?

Comment: It means I haven't determined if it does, based on the generated protocol buffer code. It shouldn't matter, given that both instances use an X == Y comparison of the exact same objects; but I note the possibility because of the phrasing of the Apple documentation for firstIndex(where:): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator "doesn't need" `Equatable`. In fact, no function, subscript, property or operator requirement of any protocol "needs" its protocol. Being present is a requirement for the protocol, but even without the protocol, nothing prevents an `==` operator from being defined, no different from any other arbitrary protocol.

I don't know what the definition of `cameraTypes()` is, but there is no difference between the `==` operator used in your `if` statement and that used in the `firtIndex(where:)` call. I don't know why it's exhibiting different behaviour for you.

Your `rawValue` example works because the `rawValue`'s type is `Int` (or some integral type, IDK the specifics of `SwiftProtobuf.Enum`), which is `Equatable` (and thus, necessarily has a `==` operator defined).

Comment: Thanks. I realize why rawValue works. cameraTypes() returns the aforementioned array of AtomCameraType. I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: Could you try to make a reproducible example of your `if` vs `firstIndex(where:)` code? I can't think of any reason why they would behave differently.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'd love to get to the bottom of it. I'll try to do that ASAP. Meanwhile, an example in the Apple doc for firstIndex(where:) says, "You can use the predicate to find an element of a type that doesn’t conform to the Equatable protocol." This inspired the phrasing of my question: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex